# How to convert flutter Icon to Image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use a standard Flutter icon as Image.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
photo = Image(image: Icons.no_photography);
```

It doesn't work because I need a path. Is there any way to find this path?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @RobertSandberg I just have an Image variable in my code and now I decided to show this icon in certain cases. I can change the code but  just decided to ask whether it is possible to avoid it. No real reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: It is not possible, the icons comes from a font.

Comment: can you somehow transform a glyph from a font into an image?